# Как нарисовать линию из символов?

Tags: c++

Дали задание, нужно нарисовать фигуру из четырёх заданных точек. Но проблема в том, что точки могут быть не только прямые, а к примеру одна из точек на 1 уровень ниже чем вторая. С выводом точек я справился, но вот как вывести кривые линии из символов, после часа гуглинга и попыток понять алгоритм Брезенхема, я так и не понял. Так-что вопрос напрашивается сам, как из символов, нарисовать линию между двумя точками (которые могут быть на одном уровне, или на разных)?
Точки мы записываем как структуру:

```
struct Point {
    int x;
    int y;
}
```

И выводим просто фигуру из символов:

```
   o***************o
   *               *
   *               *
  **               *
  *                *
  o*********       *
           ********o
```

Comment: Покажите вашу попытку реализовать алгоритм Брезенхема.

Comment: Выбрать ось по расстоянию, а потом тупо округлить.